# Are there 'independence enforcing' maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

Given two independent families of real scalar random variables $\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ and $\{Y_1, \ldots, Y_n\}$, it is clear that for any two measurable $\varphi_1, \varphi_2 : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the images
$$\tag{1}X:=\varphi_1(X_1, \ldots, X_n)\quad\text{ and }\quad Y:=\varphi_2(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n)$$ will also be independent random variables (assume $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 2}$ throughout).

Is it possible, I wonder, to construct $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ such that the converse also holds, i.e. such that
$$\tag{2}\varphi_1(X_1, \ldots, X_n), \ \varphi_2(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n) \ \text{ independent } \quad \Longrightarrow\quad \{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}, \ \{Y_1, \ldots, Y_n\} \ \text{ independent}?$$

Comment: Any injective $\phi$ will do: for example, the function that interleaves the decimal digits of the $X_i$. I think the normal name for this property would be 'independence reflecting'.

Comment: Thank you @JohnGowers !